# Any plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the plane $ax+by+cz=d$

consider the set $\mathsf{P}=\{(x,y,z):ax+by+cz=d\}$

I want to prove this result by Ball defiitio to say $\mathsf{P}$ is closed we have to say $\mathsf{P}^c$ open.

which means every ball having $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathsf{P}^c$ as its centre and $\exists   r\gt0, \mathsf{B}((x_0,y_0),r) \subseteq \mathsf{P}^c  $

considering the perpendicular distance from the point to the plane which is a shortest distance between the point and the plane is our radius.

That is, $r=\dfrac{ax+by+cz-d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$,

I have two doubt, one is,

1) How to prove this ball is in $\mathsf{P}^c$?

2)Can we extend the same idea to prove any vector subsapce is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Do you know that $f^{-1}(A)$ for a continuous function $f$ and an open set $A$ is always itself open?

Comment: I have heard, But I want proof using Ball definition.

Comment: If the closest point on the plane is distance $r$, then what does it mean to be inside the ball of radius $r$? --- How does that contradict what you know about distance $r$ if the point were on the plane?

Comment: sorry,I couldn't understand what you are saying

Answer (score 3):

To get you started then:

Let $x\in \mathbf{P}^c$. Then define $r$ as you have above.

Let $y\in b_r(x)$, the open ball of radius $r$ centered at point $x$. Write out the set definition of this ball. If $y$ were a point on $\mathbf{P}$, what would be wrong?

Once you answer this, then for all $y\in b_r(x)$, $y\in \mathbf{P}^c$, thus $b_r(x)\subset \mathbf{P}^c$, completing the proof.

---

**EDIT:**
To answer your second question, yes, you can do something similar, but you'll need to generalize $r$ to the notion of the closest point in a subspace. You'll need to look at orthogonal projections onto your subspace. (This is what you are doing in the $\mathbb{R}^3$ case onto the plane.)